# How to md5 a password before registering the user in devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, md5

In my Rails app, I use devise to manage users with devise's default configuration. I need to md5 the user-provided password before going down into the devise layer. That is, two steps are included:

```
                  (1)                 (2)
password_in_plain --- password_in_md5 --- password_in_bcrypt.
```

The first one(1) is our concern, the last one(2) is not (devise takes care of it).

I generated two devise controllers: registrations and sessions, and added a before_filter to do the job -- md5 the plain password user provided. The user can be registered with a success, but login always fail. Here is my code:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :md5_password_params, only: [:create]

  protected
  def md5_password_params
    params[:user][:password] = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(params[:user][:password])
    params[:user][:password_confirmation] = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(params[:user][:password_confirmation])
  end
end

class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  before_filter :md5_password, only: [:create]
  protected

  def md5_password
    params[:user][:password] = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(params[:user][:password])
  end
end
```

What's wrong here? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Background: one of my other server apps (written in c++) will create user records in the same database directly. For safety reason, a md5 password will be sent to this server when users make registrations in their phones.

Comment: Please don't tell me that you store passwords as md5? That's has been insecure for years already... either store them in plain text to give the bad guys a good day or use a secure hashing algorithm and completely ruin their day. Using md5 is like offering them tea and biscuits and say "thank you" when they leave with all the passwords.

Comment: @Augusto No, it's not. Actually, bcrypt is used. After md5 the plain password, then bcrypt the.md5 string.

Comment: Use something like SHA512:  Digest::SHA2.new(512).digest("my password")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this on the controller level and mucking about with the params you can create your own encryptor for Devise.

One major reason you would want to do this is that if your user fills in the registration form and submits it with invalid values both the password and confirmation fields will contain a MD5 digest of what the user originally typed. This is because you are mutating the params hash before it is fed to the model.

Submitting the form again means that the password is encrypted twice and no longer matches what the user thinks the original password is. On the plus side its extremely secure since nobody can actually guess their password ;)

Based on the current version of Devise you should be able to do something like the following to ensure the password is encrypted before a digest is created and before trying to compare plaintext with the encrypted password.

Make sure to add the `devise-encryptable` gem to your Gemfile. Its required for anything else than default encryption.

```
# config/initializers/md5.rb
require 'digest/md5'

module Devise
  module Encryptable
    module Encryptors
      class BCryptPlusMD5 < Base
        def self.digest(klass, password)
          super(klass, Digest::MD5.hexdigest(password))
        end
        def self.compare(klass, hashed_password, password)
          super(klass, hashed_password, Digest::MD5.hexdigest(password))
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You would can configure what encryptor to use in `config/initializers/devise.rb` - however I have not been able to find a good source on how the class lookup works.

- https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/encryptor.rb

Comment: Thank your reply. The reentry will be a problem. If there is no other ways, this may be a choice.